# What was the exact form of Gödel's original Second Incompleteness Theorem?

Tags: proof-verification, incompleteness

Gödel's second incompleteness theorem is usually stated as:

> Any consistent formal system $F$ capable of elementary arithmetic can't prove its own consistency.

I'm having trouble deducing this statement using just the pieces Gödel had available in 1931. As I understand it those were:

- Suppose $G$ is provable. Then this can be converted into a proof of $\neg G$. Hence, $F$ is inconsistent.
- Suppose $\neg G$ is provable. Then $F$ "believes" that $G$ can be proven. This doesn't necessarily have to be true. But at the very least $F$ is unsound.

The best I'm able to deduce from this is this:

> Any **sound** formal system $F$ capable of elementary arithmetic can't prove its own consistency.

Take the contrapositive of the first of the previous deductions. Because consistency is a syntactic property this can be fully formalized in $F$ as "$F$ is consistent $\implies$ $\neg G$ is provable". Moreover, there really isn't anything stopping us from actually proving this theorem in $F$. But then, provided $F$ is *sound*, $F$ can't prove its own consistency. If it could, then using modus ponens it could prove $\neg G$. However, that would make $F$ unsound. $\square$

This is a decidedly weaker version of the second incompleteness theorem. And I don't see how to plug the hole without invoking Rosser's Theorem. Is this all that Gödel had in 1931?

Comment: The condition that the system is consistent is crucial. Otherwise it could prove everything, in particular its own consistency.

Comment: @Peter This only shows "$F$ is inconsistent $\implies$ $F$ can prove it's own consistency". What I want is the other direction: "$F$ can prove it's own consistency $\implies$ $F$ is inconsistent".

Comment: This is of course the hard part. If we assume that $F$ is consistent, then $G$ and $"not\  G"$ cannot be both deduced. This leads to the contradiction you mentioned.

Comment: Goedel showed that , if $F$ is consistent , THEN it cannot prove its own consistency.

Comment: @Peter I still don't see at what point you tightened the reasoning compared to my argument.

Comment: To be honest, I do not understand what you actually ask. My guess was that you want to know what we have in the case that $F$ is inconsistent. It would be helpful , if you clarify your question.

Comment: @Peter I'm asking how Gödel managed to arrive at the conclusion that "$F$ is consistent $\implies$ $G$" is provable in $F$. From what I can tell, he could only establish "$F$ is *sound* $\implies$ $G$". But this  statement involves soundness and can't be formalized.

Answer (score 2):

The negation of "$G$ is provable" isn't "$\neg G$ is provable". It's "$G$ isn't provable" = $G$. The contrapositive of the first deduction is thus "$F$ is consistent $\implies$ $G$". Now suppose $F$ is consistent and can prove its own consistency. Then $F$ can prove $G$, rendering it inconsistent. ⚡

And all is well.

Comment: I've upvoted since this is correct, but I *strongly* think you should delete the self-deprecation - all this stuff is quite reasonable to find confusing, and for similar readers' sake we should avoid implying that these issues are stupid.